# Golang Post 400 bad request

Tags: go, go-chi

I am trying to do a simple login. I followed a tutorial on Udemy. It went through rendering templates with a render function. I decided I wanted to handle templates differently and not have a render function and changed everything around. But I did not touch the PostLoginHandler. Since I made this change my post for "/login" has stopped working. I get "400 bad request" and I can't figure out why. I'll include the code that I think is important. I will say that I think it has something to do with the request, and/or CRSF token the tutorial added that I have not used since the changes. I am not using template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./templates/*.tmpl")) for handling templates.

Also, I'm sorry about the long post, I wasn't sure what info would be needed. Thank you in advance for any responses.

Old render function.

```
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, t string, pd *models.PageData) {
    var tmpl *template.Template
    var err error
    _, inMap := tmplCache[t]
    if !inMap {
        err = makeTemplateCache(t)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Template in cache")
        }
    }
    tmpl = tmplCache[t]

    pd = AddCSRFData(pd, r)

    err = tmpl.Execute(w, pd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

routes

```
mux := chi.NewRouter()
mux.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
mux.Use(NoSurf)
mux.Use(SetupSession)

mux.Post("/login", handlers.Repo.PostLoginHandler)
```

It's not even getting to the PostLoginHandler, but the code is

```
func (m *Repository) PostLoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("here")

    //strMap := make(map[string]string)
    _ = m.App.Session.RenewToken(r.Context())
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    email := r.Form.Get("email")
    password := r.Form.Get("password")

    form := forms.New(r.PostForm)
    form.HasRequired("email", "password")
    form.IsEmail("email")

    if !form.Valid() {
        err := m.App.UITemplates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.page.tmpl", &models.PageData{Form: form})
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        //render.RenderTemplate(w, r, "login.page.tmpl", &models.PageData{Form: form})
        return
    }
    id, _, err := m.DB.AuthenticateUser(email, password)
    if err != nil {
        m.App.Session.Put(r.Context(), "error", "Invalid Email OR Password")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }
    m.App.Session.Put(r.Context(), "user_id", id)
    m.App.Session.Put(r.Context(), "flash", "Valid Login")
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
    //render.RenderTemplate(w, r, "page.page.tmpl", &models.PageData{StrMap: strMap})
}
```

and lastly, the HTML is a simple form

```
<form method="post" action="/login">

   {{/*<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{.CSRFToken}}">*/}}

   <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
   <div class="form-floating">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
       <label for="email">Email address</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-floating">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
       <label for="password">Password</label>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox mb-3">
       <label>
           <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
       </label>
   </div>
   <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks the issue is related with `NoSurf` middleware. How you setting up this middleware in your code? Which package used for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`400 bad request` is getting with `Nosurf` middleware.

**Firstly**, you should un-comment this in your template. As this is required for crsf validation.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{.CSRFToken}}">
```

**Secondly**, you should ensure that the `CSRFToken` correctly passed into the template. I hope this is updating within `AddCSRFData` function.

> I get "400 bad request" and I can't figure out why.

By default the package is not logging anything when an error happened. But it is possible to override the `failure handler` to see what exact reason caused the `400 bad request`.

See the sample code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
    "github.com/justinas/nosurf"
)

var formTemplate = `
    <html>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="/submit">
            <!--  comment this and see error -->
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ .CSRFToken }}"/>

            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>

            <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
`
var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("t1").Parse(formTemplate))

// FailureFunction
// Overriding the default nosurf failure Handler
func FailureFunction() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Printf("Request Failed. Reason: %v", nosurf.Reason(r))
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(nosurf.FailureCode), nosurf.FailureCode)
    })
}

// NoSurf
// Setting up the handler with overrriding default nosurf failure Handler
func NoSurf(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    obj := nosurf.New(handler)
    obj.SetFailureHandler(FailureFunction()) // Override default failure Handler
    return obj
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    // Add middleware
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    r.Use(NoSurf)

    r.Get("/", HomeHandler)
    r.Post("/submit", SubmitHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    token := nosurf.Token(r) // generating the token

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "CSRFToken": token, // comment this and see the error
    }
    err := tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "unable to execute the template", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func SubmitHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Bad Request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if !nosurf.VerifyToken(nosurf.Token(r), r.PostForm.Get("csrf_token")) {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid CSRF Token", http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte("success"))
}
```

Hoping this will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you. This worked. This helped a lot. I was able to figure out how to incorporate that "AddCSRFData" function back in... I guess i didn't realize how important that was to the code.